# Strange Pandas Behaviour Updating NaN with Previous Row's Value

Tags: python, pandas

If I have data from an Excel spreadsheet - the format dictates that only rows that change have the first column filled in (other entries are blank).  That value is then assumed to persist for the next N rows until the value changes again.

So Pandas imports this as shown below - no suprises here:

**Animal**
Cat
NaN
NaN
NaN
Dog
NaN
NaN
Cow
NaN

I need to replace the NaNs with the last valid value - so in the above example:

**Animal**
Cat
Cat
Cat
Cat
Dog
Dog
Dog
Cow
Cow

I came up with, the following, assuming column name of Animal:

df.Animal.where(~df.Animal.isnull(), df.Animal.shift())

If Pandas runs in sequence then it should the previous "animal" should always be filled in - but when I run this I see that only the first NaN representing Cat, Dog and Cow are updated, the other NaNs remain.

If I replace the shift() with a hardcoded string it works, so the logic looks good.

I assume this means that Pandas does not run in strict sequence, and is probably parallelizing the map operation.

In which case (or if I'm doing something else wrong) - how can I do this?

Thanks!

Phil.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try [`ffill`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.18.1/generated/pandas.DataFrame.ffill.html):

```
df.Animal.ffill()
Out[68]: 
  Animal
0    Cat
1    Cat
2    Cat
3    Cat
4    Dog
5    Dog
6    Dog
7    Cow
8    Cow
```

This is equivalent to `fillna(method='ffill')`:

```
s.Animal.fillna(method='ffill')
Out[72]: 
0    Cat
1    Cat
2    Cat
3    Cat
4    Dog
5    Dog
6    Dog
7    Cow
8    Cow
Name: Animal, dtype: object
```

Edit: To further answer your question, consider the following:

First, find where `df['Animal']` is null:

```
df.Animal.isnull()
Out[76]: 
0    False
1     True
2     True
3     True
4    False
5     True
6     True
7    False
8     True
Name: Animal, dtype: bool
```

Let's see what happens if we replace these null values with 1s:

```
df.Animal.where(~df.Animal.isnull(), 1)
Out[77]: 
0    Cat
1      1
2      1
3      1
4    Dog
5      1
6      1
7    Cow
8      1
Name: Animal, dtype: object
```

Okay, that makes sense. So, why doesn't replacing with `df.Animal.shift()` work?

```
df.Animal.shift()
Out[78]: 
0    NaN
1    Cat
2    NaN
3    NaN
4    NaN
5    Dog
6    NaN
7    NaN
8    Cow
Name: Animal, dtype: object
```

The line `df.Animal.where(~df.Animal.isnull(), df.Animal.shift())` doesn't work because, as you can see above, the values for `Animal` at indices 2, 3, etc. are `NaN`. They aren't updated on-the-fly, like you seem to think they are. Your line of code is replacing the `NaN` values in `df['Animal']` with the corresponding shifted value at that particular index. So that's why "Cat" is only filled down once, because the next value in the shifted column is `NaN`.

If you're still unsure, try going through each step of your line of code and seeing what the objects are for each parameter, like I did above.

Comment: Yes! The certianly solves problem - many thanks!  Still curious to why my original construction fails before I close the question off.

Comment: Yes - this is what I suspected - thanks again, very helpful!